# Error while returning value from async dns.lookup() function

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, dns

I'm writing a function to verify a `url` using `dns.lookup()` function as defined below:

```
const dns = require('dns');

const verifyURL = (url) => {
  const protocolRegEx = /^https?:\/\/(.*)/i;
  const hostnameRegEx = /^([a-z0-9\-_]+\.)+[a-z0-9\-_]+/i;

  if (url.match(/\/$/i)) {
    url = url.slice(0,-1);
  }

  const protocol = url.match(protocolRegEx);
  if (!protocol) { 
    return false;
  }

  const hostname = protocol[1].match(hostnameRegEx);
  if (hostname) {
    dns.lookup(hostname[0], (err, adderss) => {
      if (err) return false;
      return adderss;
    })
  }
}
```

I'm trying to return either `true` or `false` from inside of the `callback` passed to the `dns.lookup()` function.

```
(async () => { 
  let x = await verifyURL('https://stackoverflow.com/')
  console.log(x);
})();
```

But everytime I run this code I get `undefined` as return value.
I already tried this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54887214), but it's not working.
Please help me. Thank  you!!

Comment: My understanding is `async await` works with Promises. Should you be using the DNS Promises API instead?

Answer (score 1):

You are awaiting a function, verifyURL, which does not return a promise.

One option is to modify your `verifyURL` function to return a promise.

```js
  const verifyURL = (url) => {
    const protocolRegEx = /^https?:\/\/(.*)/i;
    const hostnameRegEx = /^([a-z0-9\-_]+\.)+[a-z0-9\-_]+/i;

    if (url.match(/\/$/i)) {
      url = url.slice(0,-1);
    }

    const protocol = url.match(protocolRegEx);
    if (!protocol) {
      return false;
    }

    const hostname = protocol[1].match(hostnameRegEx);

    //verify this! I add this to return false if !hostname
    if (!hostname) {
      return false
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      dns.lookup(hostname[0], (err, address) => {
        if (err) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        // Here I resolve to address. You can resolve to true as you mention in your post.
        return resolve(address)
      });
    });
  }
```

Also you should handle the rejection of the promise.
E.g. looking for https://stackoverflow2.com will give you an error "getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND stackoverflow2.com"

```js
  (async () => {
    try {
      let x = await verifyURL('https://stackoverflow.com')
      console.log(x);
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e.message)
    }
  })();
```

Another option is to use [dns promise api](https://nodejs.org/api/dns.html#dns_dns_promises_api)